# IE taking script(dynamically added) from cache when added to onclick handler

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, caching, internet-explorer-9

**[IE9]** Consider the following code:

```
var scr = document.createElement("script");
scr.src = "http://collector.bonzai.mobi/expfreq?hours=1&freq=1&adid=abc&sn=source1&pub=publisher";
scr.onload = function(){
    alert("openPage " + openPage);
}
document.body.appendChild(scr);
```

The problem is when I put this code directly in a  `<script>`  tag it works fine (means every time it contact server for retreiving the script). But if I keep the same code inside  `document.onclick`  function the **IE9** is taking the script from cache 2nd time on wards. (I can see the 304 and <1ms)

**PS** : I cannot use  `Date.now()`  or any sort of cache bursting mechanism to append at the end of URL because the backend implementation depends of Cache (ETag).

Also I would suggest you clear your cache in IE browser before attempting each code change.

Any advice would be of great help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution for the problem. Setting "Cache-Control:private, must-revalidate" header from server solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

a solution from the client side could be :

```
scr.src = "http://collector.bonzai.mobi/expfreq?hours=1&freq=1&adid=abc&sn=source1&pub=publisher&timestamp=" + new Date().getTime();
```

So each request won't be cached.